# .slideToggle() Runs With a Lagging/Jerky Animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

So I have read a lot of the other posts and none of them seem to be of any help.
Whenever I toggle up the animation jumps and shows some lag.

**Here is my CSS:**

```
<style>
margin:0 auto;
padding:0;
width:200px;
text-align:center;
}
.pull-me {
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 8px #FFD700;
-moz-box-shadow: 0 0 8px #FFD700;
box-shadow: 0 0 8px #FFD700;
cursor:pointer;
}
.panel {
background: #white;
background-size:90% 90%;
height:300px;
display:none;
font-family:garamond, times-new-roman, serif;
}
.panel p {
text-align:center;
}
.slide {
margin:0;
padding:0;
border-top:solid 2px #a10808;
}
.pull-me {
display:block;
position:relative;
border: 1px;
right:-25px;
width:150px;
height:20px;
font-family:arial, sans-serif;
font-size:14px;
color:#ffffff;
background:#a10808;
text-decoration:none;
-moz-border-bottom-left-radius:5px;
-moz-border-bottom-right-radius:5px;
border-bottom-left-radius:5px;
border-bottom-right-radius:5px;
}
.pull-me p {
text-align:center;
}
</style>
```

**Below is my HTML:**

```
<div class="panel" style="width: 100%; overflow: hidden;">
    <div style="width: 100px; float: left;"></div>
</div>
<p class="slide">
    <div class="pull-me">Directory</div>
</p>
```

**Below is my jQuery:**

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
$('.pull-me').click(function () {
    $('.panel').slideToggle('slow');
});
});


</script>
```

I am using `IE9` and I have not been able to use any other browser.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: what do you mean with "the animation jumps"?  i've made a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Uds4z/) with your code and it works

Comment: Do you mean when you toggle down and the content shows? or when you toggle up and the content hides

Comment: @imbondbaby when I toggle up it jumps at the end of the animation also my css is missing part of the code it is body{ for the first part of my css

Comment: Does inserting the body tag fix your issue?

Answer (score 0):

I supouse you have missed a line in your css it should start like this:

```
<style>
div {
    margin:0 auto;
    ...
```

or just delete these lines

```
margin:0 auto;
padding:0;
width:200px;
text-align:center;
}
```

Comment: I am missing a body tag at the beginning of the css